# Number of iterations to achieve the desired convergence accuracy

Tags: convergence-divergence

For a small constant $\varepsilon>0$ and positive integer $n$, 
we are given a sequence of $(0,1)$-reals 
 $\left\{a_0,a_1,\dots\right\}$, with $a_0=n^{-\varepsilon}$ and 
$$
a_{i+1}=\left(\frac{a_i}{1-a_i}\right)^2.
$$
The question is about determining the minimal integer $i$ (or some reasonable lower-bound) such that $a_i$ drops below $\frac{1}{n}$. Clearly, the limit (or fixed point of the function) is $0$, and the [rate of convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_of_convergence) seems to be quadratic.

Intuitively, by $\left(\frac{a}{1-a}\right)^2<\frac{a^2}{1-2a}\sim a^2$, I suspect the result to be close to $-\log_{2}\varepsilon$, at least for big enough $n$, however I would need somehow more precise statement.

Answer (score 1):

Since
$a_{i+1}
=\left(\dfrac{a_i}{1-a_i}\right)^2
$,
$\dfrac{a_{i+1}}{a_i}
=\dfrac{a_i}{(1-a_i)^2}
$.

Since
$\dfrac1{1-x}
\le 1+2x
$
for
$1 \le 1+x-2x^2
$
or
$x \le \frac12$,
if
$a_i \le\frac15 < \frac12$,

$\begin{array}\\
a_{i+1}
&=\dfrac{a_i^2}{(1-a_i)^2}\\
&\le a_i^2(1+2a_i)^2 \\
&= a_i^2(1+4a_i+4a_i^2)\\
&= a_i^2(1+4a_i(1+a_i))\\
&= a_i^2(1+5a_i)\\
&\le 2a_i^2\\
\text{so}\\
a_{i+k}
&\le (2a_i)^{2^{k-1}}\\
\end{array}
$

Note:
The exponent of $2$
may be not quite right,
but the exponent of
$a_i$ probably is correct.

Comment: Thank you for an answer; I believe your arguments gives a bound of $2^{2^{k+1}}\cdot a_i^{2^k}$. For the sake of formal correctness, I think your statements could be improved in a couple of details... I'll fix them in the evening if you don't want to do it yourself by then.

Comment: I was rushed when I did it, so I am not surprised if there are minor errors. Make any corrections you want.